# How to refresh/flush cache automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, error, cache

Every single time I am trying to **upload** a **few photos**, the Cache says "One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Blocks HTML output. Click here to go to Cache Management and refresh cache types." I know that you can go in and select all to refresh or flush, but if I try to go to the cache management page or any page in the website, a white page saying "This page isn’t working" pops up until I clear the cache through cpanel FTP or wait for a good few minutes to reload the page. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: you can do cache management programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    include 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();

    echo "cleared cache";
?>
```

Comment: Where is the directory for that? Thank you

Comment: root folder ......

Comment: I know it's in the root folder, but which file do I have to insert this code to?

Comment: you have to create a new file for this ex: clearcache.php
in browser you have to run http://website.com/clearcache.php

Comment: ok let me know the status

Comment: I have to upload few more image to check if it works so I'll let you know the status in a day or two. Thanks once again. I will let you know!

Comment: It seems like its still the same.. It says i have to reenable the cache and if i ignore it and keep uploading photos, it will stop uploading photos and if i refresh, "This page isn’t working" page pops up. I have to either go to cpanel ftp and delete the cache or wait good few minutes and refresh the page for it to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question assuming you are using Magento 1.

Check function **invalidateType** in file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php

This function marks the cache as invalidated. You can hook the code of this function to clean the cache instead of marking it as invalidated.

I hope it will help.